# How to Export Datagridview to Excel Workbook

Tags: excel, vb.net

I am running into an issue while trying to export a Datagridview to an excel workbook. I have 2 different codes, the first one throws an error about a null value and the second exports the data to excel but its missing the headers and a column or 2. Any direction you can give would be mush appreciated.

This one throws a Null Error

```
        'Creating DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable()

        'Adding the Columns
        For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
            dt.Columns.Add(column.HeaderText, column.ValueType)
        Next

        'Adding the Rows
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            dt.Rows.Add()
            For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                dt.Rows(dt.Rows.Count - 1)(cell.ColumnIndex) = cell.Value.ToString()
            Next
        Next

        'Exporting to Excel

        Dim folderPath As String = "C:\Users\" & UserName & "\Desktop\SkyNet Exports"
        If Not My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(folderPath) Then
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(folderPath)
        End If
        Dim wb As New Excel.Application()
        wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "Skills")
        wb.SaveAs(folderPath & Convert.ToString("SkyNet Export.xlsx"))
```

And this one exports to excel but with missing columns and no headers

```
    Private Sub ExportToExcel()

        Dim ExcelApp As Object, ExcelBook As Object
        Dim ExcelSheet As Object
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer

        'create object of excel
        ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        ExcelBook = ExcelApp.WorkBooks.Add
        ExcelSheet = ExcelBook.WorkSheets(1)

        With ExcelSheet
            For i = 1 To Me.DataGridView1.RowCount
                .cells(i, 1) = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i - 1).Cells("id").Value
                For j = 1 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
                    .cells(i, j + 1) = DataGridView1.Rows(i - 1).Cells(j).Value
                Next
            Next
        End With

        ExcelApp.Visible = True
        '
        ExcelSheet = Nothing
        ExcelBook = Nothing
        ExcelApp = Nothing

    End Sub
```

Once again any help is appreciated, I have looked at different sites but most are not using VB.Net

Here is the error for the first code
[Code Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDyeG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with the 2nd code. I tried to use your code and it didnt work at first but then I noticed you had named the column index as ColumnIndex, and it was actually needed to be names colIndex, Thanks for all your help.

Here is the finished code,

````
    Private Sub ExportToExcel()

        Dim ExcelApp As Object, ExcelBook As Object
        Dim ExcelSheet As Object
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer

        'create object of excel
        ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        ExcelBook = ExcelApp.WorkBooks.Add
        ExcelSheet = ExcelBook.WorkSheets(1)

        Dim rowIndex As Integer = 1
        Dim colIndex As Integer = 1

        ''For Headers  
        With ExcelSheet
            For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In Me.DataGridView1.Columns
                If column.Name = "Id" Then
                    .cells(rowIndex, 1) = column.HeaderText
                Else

                    .cells(rowIndex, colIndex) = column.HeaderText
                    colIndex = colIndex + 1
                End If
            Next
        End With


        ''For Rows
        With ExcelSheet
            For i = 0 To Me.DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
                If Not IsNothing(Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value) Then
                    rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
                    colIndex = 1


                    For j = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
                        If DataGridView1.Columns(j).Name = "Id" Then
                            .cells(rowIndex, 1) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value
                        Else
                            .cells(rowIndex, colIndex) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value
                            colIndex = colIndex + 1
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        End With

        ExcelApp.Visible = True
        '
        ExcelSheet = Nothing
        ExcelBook = Nothing
        ExcelApp = Nothing

    End Sub
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

In 2nd code you miss to add headers and also while your try to get column values you started your j iterator with 1 so value at 1st column will be missing (if your id column is not a 1st column)

```
Private Sub ExportToExcel()

        Dim ExcelApp As Object, ExcelBook As Object
        Dim ExcelSheet As Object
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer

        'create object of excel
        ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        ExcelBook = ExcelApp.WorkBooks.Add
        ExcelSheet = ExcelBook.WorkSheets(1)

       dim rowIndex as integer = 1 
       dim colIndex as integer = 2
       
       ''For Headers  
       With ExcelSheet
            For each column as datagridviewcolumn in Me.DataGridView1.columns
               if column.name = "Id" then 
                      .cells(rowindex, 1) = Column.HeaderText
                else 

                .cells(rowindex, colIndex) = Column.HeaderText
                colIndex = ColIndex + 1 
                end if 
            Next
        End With

        

        With ExcelSheet
            For i = 0 To Me.DataGridView1.RowCount-1
               if not isnothing (Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).value) then
               rowindex = rowIndex + 1 
               ColumnIndex = 2
 
              
                For j = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
                     if datagridview1.columns(j).name = "Id" then 
                          .cells(rowindex, 1) =   DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value     
                     else 
                        .cells(rowindex, columnIndex ) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value
                         ColumnIndex = ColumnIndex + 1 
                     End if 
                Next
             End if 
            Next
        End With

        ExcelApp.Visible = True
        '
        ExcelSheet = Nothing
        ExcelBook = Nothing
        ExcelApp = Nothing

    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to reply. I tried the above code and I get an error, "Value of type Integer cannot be converted to DataGridViewColumn".

Comment: Debug the code and let me know which line you have error

Comment: Hello Yogesh, thank you for helping on this, I pasted the code in a new form and the error is on line 23, 

```
            For column As DataGridViewColumn Me.DataGridView1.columns
```

Comment: Replace that line with ```for each column As DataGridViewColumn in Me.DataGridView1.columns```

Answer (score 0):

In 1st Code , you need to try following changes (Header text should not be duplicate in datagridview, It is better to add columnname in your datatable )

```
      'Adding the Columns
        For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
            dt.Columns.Add(column.Name, column.ValueType)
        Next
   'Adding the Rows
        dim dr as datarow 
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            dr = dt.Newrow 
            For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                 If not isnothing(cell.value) then

                       dr(datagridview1.columns(cell.ColumnIndex).Name)=  cell.Value
                End if
            Next
            dt.rows.add (dr) 
        Next
```

Comment: For this one its giving an error on " dr(datagridview1.columns(cell.ColumnIndex).headerText)= cell.Value.ToString()" its saying Column "ID" does not belong to table.

Comment: You should keep Adding  columns section

Comment: Debug the code and check columns in `dt` is same as columns in `datagridview1`

Comment: Error on this line "dr(DataGridView1.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).Name) = cell.Value.ToString()"

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object

System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.Value.get returned Nothing

Comment: Check edited answer ...Here I upload only logic not tested code you should try to correct code